# K6 browser vitals metric

Tags: javascript

Кто может подсказать почему отсутствуют некоторые vitals метрики и что надо поставить чтобы появились?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переменные

K6_BROWSER_DEBUG=true

K6_BROWSER_HEADLESS=false

K6_BROWSER_IGNORE_DEFAULT_ARGS=enable-features